# How to implement ApplicationRunner before springboot application starts?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

By reading [Spring-boot docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-spring-application.html) I have understood that I can create a class implementing `ApplicationRunner` or `CommandLineRunner` in order to execute code before application starts.

From docs:

> An ApplicationReadyEvent is sent after any application and command-line runners have been called. It indicates that the application is ready to service requests.

However, I have following class:

```
@Component
public class MyClass implements ApplicationRunner {

  @Override
  public void run(ApplicationArguments args) throws Exception {
    Thread.sleep(10000);
  }
}
```

And instead of waiting those 10 seconds to start, it says application started in 3seconds:

> 2018-11-19 08:51:21.906  INFO 24872 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
>
> 2018-11-19 08:51:21.909  INFO 24872 --- [           main] com.mycompany.Application     : Started Application in 3.565 seconds (JVM running for 4.016)

I assume my class is running in another thread. But I have the feeling that this does not guarantee that my code has finished executing before any possible incoming request.

Is this the correct approach? Am I missing something?

Comment: Your understanding is wrong. The `ApplicationRunner` and `CommandLineRunner` are part of Spring Boot. Beans of that type will be detected as soon as the application has started (the `ApplicationContext` is up and running). All of this is part of the starting of the application. If you want anything to execute before Spring Boot does anything do it before the call to `SpringApplication.run` in your code.

Comment: Problem is that I would like to use @Components. I have found a solution, by using events listeners. Following docs: "3. An ApplicationPreparedEvent is sent just before the refresh is started but after bean definitions have been loaded." I just wondered if I could use the ApplicationRunner or CommandLineRunner somehow in same thread

Comment: No as those are executed right before the `ApplicationReadyEvent` is published as those need a fully operation application. What do you want to do? Describe what you want to achieve and state what you tried to do.

Comment: I want to execute some kind of "setup code" which needs to be executed first of all in the application. However, this code I have it modelled via spring boots beans. I am also following this tutorial, which summarized what I want to do: https://www.baeldung.com/running-setup-logic-on-startup-in-spring

Comment: What kind of setup code.

Comment: Making changes in database. Adding columns, migrating some data between different tables... etc. So if an incoming request comes to my application, and executes code before this changes are done, it might crash due to different db schema information

Comment: Shouldn't you be using Flyway or Liquibase for that?

Comment: I thought about it, but it's for my company, and they do not want developers to waste time understanding that library, since we are in a kind of a hurry. So we need pure java code everyone is able to develop fast. Moreover, I do not know much about those, but I'm not sure if they give you as much freedom as a real programming language

Comment: So instead of reading documentation of a well used and established library you decide to write your own which everyone who understands Liquibase of Flyway now needs to learn... Also Flyway and Liquibase allows you to have Java migrations perfectly well. Also doing stuff in java can actually slow things down compared of doing them in raw SQL.

Comment: Well, it's not my decision :( can't do nothing about it. We talked about doin that later on, when we have more time

Comment: Which will never be the case... There is no such thing as a temporary solution. (In my 20 years of experience).

Comment: Anyway, that's another problem we have, that I do agree with you. But I think is out of the question. I can not understand that spring boot does not provide me a solution to execute code during it's lifecycle. I did not understand the problem you talked about with `ApplicationReadyEvent` needing a fully operation application. What do you mean exactly? Using this event, it looks like working for my case :S

Comment: You are using an `ApplicationPreparedEvent` NOT an `ApplicationReadyEvent` those are different events fired at different times in the lifecycle of bootstrapping the application.

Comment: Have you already tried the applicationStartedEvent? You could create a Component that implements ApplicationListener<ApplicationStartedEvent>. According to the documentation the overridden method onApplicationEvent is getting called once the application context had been refreshed but before any application command line runners are being executed... https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/context/event/ApplicationStartedEvent.html you could also try the ApplicationPreparedEvent instead of ApplicationStartedEvent as M.Deinum suggested